# How I can connect by ajax json tomcat from localhost to another server

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, tomcat, jsonp

How I can connect by ajax json tomcat from localhost to another server to get a json.
If I do the query location by entering the url in the browser returns a correct json, but if I do it with jquery ajax fails me. I've tried with jsonp and does not work.
I changed the url of ajax on the other and it works.

```
             $.ajax({    
                url : myUrl,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                jsonp : 'json.wrf',
                jsonpCallback: 'loadData',
                dataFilter: function(data) {
                    alert('filter');
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('success');
                },
                error: function(d,msg) {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You stumbled upon the browser's Same Origin Policy. If you have administrative access to the server, you should either implement JSONP or set the response header to allow external origins

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Comment: I don't have access to the server.

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid, your options are limited. You could use a serverside proxy on your localhost to "relay" the request. For your script the request will go to localhost only (which is allowed), the server script will request the JSON from the external server (which is also allowed) and forward it to your local javascript

Comment: It returns: XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{8a2c3f7c-b688-4f2d-8a4b-6854e0c4b834} Line Number 1, Column 1:

Comment: Did you set a correct dataType for the ajax request? Seems like jQuery is guessing the data type as XML which is obviously wrong. Try to set it to `dataType: "json"` or `"jsonp"` respectively